# Flexbox: space between items in grid

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a responsive layout with media queries with flexbox. I need to make a layout with two sidebars on the right, right under each other, like this:
[Image: aside right under the related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ0ry.jpg) 
The current situation is like this (I'm able to move the box to the right too, but there is still a white space under the related, even though the height is good). [Image: aside is on the the next line and not under the related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3WaV.jpg)
Simplified code:

```
body {
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: row;
}

header {
 flex: 0 1 25%;
}

main {
 flex: 0 1 40%;
}

.related {
 flex: 0 1 17%;
 height: 100%;
}

aside {
 flex: 0 1 17%;
}

footer {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

I can't put a wrapper for these two boxes in the HTML (I can't use a wrapper in the HTML itself, hence I use the body as flex container). Is what I want even possible with flexbox, or what kind of other technique could I use for this? I tried a lot of different things with the height, I even tried Javascript to make a dynamic wrapper, but that didn't work well with the media queries...

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is the HTML...just the 5 elements? Are we allowed to change the HTML at all?

Comment: We can't change the HTML at all unfortunately. The HTML is just a header, a main element, an aside, a related class and a footer (all these elements have more HTML in it, but I don't think that's relevant?).

Comment: Then off-hand...I'd say you are SOL. Sorry. What was wrong with the JS wrapper...you could combine that with a media query couldn't you?

Comment: I made a function that adds the wrapper at the right place in the DOM. I just don't manage to get it working together with the media queries in JS. Javascript doesn't seem to recognize em's, and I have to use those. I also don't manage to get the eventListener working.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that what you have is a JS problem...not a flexbox one. Perhaps asking a new question (you might want to delete this one) showing what you tried. PS. Demos are good...you might want to include one on the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of body as a flex container, should not be a problem, unless there is a design problem. i think you should make layout design like
    `<http://codepen.io/erdysson/pen/wKyEzZ%20>`
I hope, this solves the problem and is what you want.

Comment: Thank you :-) I'm going to try with Javascript once again to add the additional HTML element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving the expected result without modifying your HTML markup with `flexbox` is a bit tricky.

However i believe the following example will help you, even though it´s not using the `flexbox`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header,
aside,
footer,
.main,
.related {
  min-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
header {
  width: 25%;
  background: #f00;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.main {
  width: 50%;
  background: #0f0;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.related {
  width: 25%;
  background: #0ff;
}
aside {
  width: 25%;
  background: #f0f;
  float: right;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ff0;
}
header:after,
aside:after,
footer:after,
.main:after,
.related:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<header data-title="header"></header>

<div class="main" data-title="main"></div>

<div class="related" data-title="related"></div>

<aside data-title="aside"></aside>

<footer data-title="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it another try with Javascript (I added another question for that). If that doesn't work, I'll try it with this code :)